# How to only return X amount of embedded documents with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a large collection called `posts`, like so:

```
[{
   _id: 349348jf49rk,
   user: frje93u45t,
   comments: [{
      _id: fks9272ewt
      user: 49wnf93hr9,
      comment: "Hello world"
   }, {
      _id: j3924je93h
      user: 49wnf93hr9,
      comment: "Heya"
   }, {
      _id: 30283jt9dj
      user: dje394ifjef,
      comment: "Text"
   }, {
      _id: dkw9278467
      user: fgsgrt245,
      comment: "Hola"
   }, {
      _id: 4irt8ej4gt
      user: 49wnf93hr9,
      comment: "Test"
   }]
}]
```

My `comments` subdocument can sometimes be 100s of documents long. My question is, how can I return just the 3 newest documents (based on the ID) instead of all the documents, and return the length of all documents as `totalNumberOfComments` as a count instead? I need to do this for 100s of `posts` sometimes. This is what the final result would look like:

```
[{
   _id: 349348jf49rk,
   user: frje93u45t,
   totalNumberOfComments: 5,
   comments: [{
      _id: fks9272ewt
      user: 49wnf93hr9,
      comment: "Hello world"
   }, {
      _id: j3924je93h
      user: 49wnf93hr9,
      comment: "Heya"
   }, {
      _id: 30283jt9dj
      user: dje394ifjef,
      comment: "Text"
   }]
}]
```

I understand that this could be completed after MongoDB returns the data by splicing, although I think it would be best to do this within the query so that Mongo doesn't have to return all `comments` for every single `post` all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem? try plugging in the _id values and see what you are missing and post them here.

begin with this query

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {_id: 349348jf49rk}},
                        {$project:{
                                    _id:1,
                                     user:1,
                                     totalNumberOfComments: { $size: "$comments" },
                                     comments: {$slice:3}
                                }
                        }
                    ])
```

Comment: Perfect. Just had to change the `$slice` to be `$slice: ["$comments", 3]` since `$slice` inside `aggregate` requires two arguments. Other than that, all good! Thanks JBone.